# setting kernel arguments in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I'm trying to run my first codes in OpenCL and am using the book OpenCL in Action. Here is the code for one the sample of the book. This code doesn't run and apparently fails at setting the kernel arguments. When I run the code, the printed output is: "Couldn't set the buffer as the kernel argument". The code works well on AMD but it is not working when I run it on NVIDIA platform. Any ideas why the code doesn't run properly?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define PROGRAM_FILE "blank.cl"
#define KERNEL_FUNC "blank"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef MAC
#include <OpenCL/cl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif

/* Find a GPU or CPU associated with the first available platform */
cl_device_id create_device() {

    cl_platform_id platform;
    cl_device_id dev;
    int err;

    /* Identify a platform */
    err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't identify a platform");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Access a device */
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &dev, NULL);
    if (err == CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND) {
        err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &dev, NULL);
    }
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't access any devices");
        exit(1);
    }

    return dev;
}

/* Create program from a file and compile it */
cl_program build_program(cl_context ctx, cl_device_id dev, const char* filename) {

    cl_program program;
    FILE *program_handle;
    char *program_buffer, *program_log;
    size_t program_size, log_size;
    int err;

    /* Read program file and place content into buffer */
    program_handle = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (program_handle == NULL) {
        perror("Couldn't find the program file");
        exit(1);
    }
    fseek(program_handle, 0, SEEK_END);
    program_size = ftell(program_handle);
    rewind(program_handle);
    program_buffer = (char*)malloc(program_size + 1);
    program_buffer[program_size] = '\0';
    fread(program_buffer, sizeof(char), program_size, program_handle);
    fclose(program_handle);

    /* Create program from file */
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(ctx, 1,
        (const char**)&program_buffer, &program_size, &err);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't create the program");
        exit(1);
    }
    free(program_buffer);

    /* Build program */
    err = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (err < 0) {

        /* Find size of log and print to std output */
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, dev, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,
            0, NULL, &log_size);
        program_log = (char*)malloc(log_size + 1);
        program_log[log_size] = '\0';
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, dev, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,
            log_size + 1, program_log, NULL);
        printf("%s\n", program_log);
        free(program_log);
        exit(1);
    }

    return program;
}

int main() {

    /* OpenCL data structures */
    cl_device_id device;
    cl_context context;
    cl_command_queue queue;
    cl_program program;
    cl_kernel kernel;
    cl_int i, j, err;

    /* Data and buffers */
    float data_one[100], data_two[100], result_array[100];
    cl_mem buffer_one, buffer_two;
    void* mapped_memory;

    /* Initialize arrays */
    for (i = 0; i<100; i++) {
        data_one[i] = 1.0f*i;
        data_two[i] = -1.0f*i;
        result_array[i] = 0.0f;
    }

    /* Create a device and context */
    device = create_device();
    context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &err);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't create a context");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Build the program and create the kernel */
    program = build_program(context, device, PROGRAM_FILE);
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, KERNEL_FUNC, &err);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't create a kernel");
        exit(1);
    };

    /* Create buffers */
    buffer_one = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE |
        CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(data_one), data_one, &err);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't create a buffer object");
        exit(1);
    }
    buffer_two = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE |
        CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(data_two), data_two, NULL);

    /* Set buffers as arguments to the kernel */
    err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &buffer_one);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &buffer_two);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't set the buffer as the kernel argument");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Create a command queue */
    queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device, 0, &err);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't create a command queue");
        exit(1);
    };

    /* Enqueue kernel */
    err = clEnqueueTask(queue, kernel, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't enqueue the kernel");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Enqueue command to copy buffer one to buffer two */
    err = clEnqueueCopyBuffer(queue, buffer_one, buffer_two, 0, 0,
        sizeof(data_one), 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't perform the buffer copy");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Enqueue command to map buffer two to host memory */
    mapped_memory = clEnqueueMapBuffer(queue, buffer_two, CL_TRUE,
        CL_MAP_READ, 0, sizeof(data_two), 0, NULL, NULL, &err);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't map the buffer to host memory");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Transfer memory and unmap the buffer */
    memcpy(result_array, mapped_memory, sizeof(data_two));
    err = clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(queue, buffer_two, mapped_memory,
        0, NULL, NULL);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't unmap the buffer");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Display updated buffer */
    for (i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j<10; j++) {
            printf("%6.1f", result_array[j + i * 10]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    /* Deallocate resources */
    clReleaseMemObject(buffer_one);
    clReleaseMemObject(buffer_two);
    clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
    clReleaseProgram(program);
    clReleaseContext(context);

    return 0;
}
```

and here is the kernel in a separate blank.cl file:

```
__kernel void blank(__global float *a, __global float *b) {
}
```

Comment: And where is blank.cl?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that. I have added the kernel at the end of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that the problem was because of wrong kernel declaration in the separate *.cl file. The code is working properly. I just had the wrong kernel!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you run it on Windows. This code doesn't take into account Windows EOL which is 2 characters: '\r\n' and the last character after reading the kernel from file is '\r' which OpenCL compiler cannot digest.

There are 2 options - you can either convert blank.cl file to unix format or
add `program_buffer[program_size-1] = '\0';` after `program_buffer[program_size] = '\0';`.

Comment: I run it on Windows actually. When I run it on Windows 10 with AMD device it works properly, but it doesn't work on Windows 10 on NVIDIA.

Comment: Not all compilers are the same, one may be OK with '\r' another not. I tested it with Nvidia on Windows 7 and it required one of the changes I suggested. Have you tried it?

Comment: If this is really the reason, I would recommend embedding the cl kernel in the code as a string and try. You can do it with: `const char * kern = R"[ #include "mykern.cl" ]";`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I figured out that the problem was because of wrong kernel declaration.